# How can i replace " in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, replace

How can i replace this string:

```
<say"Hello">
```

with another strings in VB.net?
this program is not working!!

```
Text1.Text = Text1.Text.Replace("<say"Hello">", " ")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a literal quote in a string, use a double quote (`""`) as so:

```
Text1.Text = Text1.Text.Replace("<say""Hello"">", " ")
```

The string will then be interpreted as this:

```
<say"Hello">
```